# What's this function by Ramanujan?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

In this paper by Ramanujan (http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram32.pdf), he writes the following formula:
$$[x] = \pi_1(x) + \pi_2(x) + \pi_3(x) + \cdots ,$$
what exactly is the function on the LHS? Is it the floor function?

Comment: it is written two lines above..

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, I may be wrong, but two lines above is written "It has been proved by Landau". There is no reference to $[x]$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde two lines above it is written that πk(x) is the number of positive integers which do not exceed x and have exactly k prime factors, and that the formula is "obvious"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  LHS is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), the RHS is $\pi_k(x)$,  the number of positive integers which do not exceed $x$ and have exactly $k$ prime factors.

Comment: Is it just a redundancy? I mean, doesn't πk(x) only work for integers?

Comment: No, $\pi_k(x)$ works for real numbers $x\ge 1$.

Comment: How can reals be prime factorized?

Comment: The number of positive integers $m\le x$ which have exactly $k$ prime factors. So prime factors of $m$ and not of $x$.

Comment: Oh! That's what I've been missing. Thanks mate.